# HTTP ERROR: 503 when i run app-engine locally

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-development-server

I try to debug my java servlet with app engine locally:

```
/opt/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.42/bin/dev_appserver.sh -p 8090 /Users/me/proj/src/main/webapp
```

and i see:

```
Oct 01, 2016 9:26:27 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8090
Oct 01, 2016 9:26:27 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8090/
Oct 01, 2016 9:26:27 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8090/_ah/admin
Oct 01, 2016 12:26:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

I navigate to `http://localhost:8090/demo`

but get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /demo. Reason:

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
Powered by Jetty://
```

here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myapp.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>check</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myapp.CheckServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/demo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>check</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/check</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: web.xml configuration looks fine to me. I couldn't deduce much from this code as there could be some external cause. Are you able to access admin console http://localhost:8090/_ah/admin ?

Comment: `HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /_ah/admin. Reason:

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same issue before. I found out that this error could occur if your server is trying to look for a file in your directory that doesn't exist. After doing console.log() and looking through my directory for 30 minutes, I just deleted my project and cloned the github repository onto my computer again. Then, localhost:8080 started working normally again.